# mysql insert into table from multiple select queries

Tags: mysql

How do i combine this into a single insert

```
INSERT INTO masterTable (count1) select count(*) as count1 from tablex
INSERT INTO masterTable (count2) select count(*) as count2 from tabley
INSERT INTO masterTable (count3) select count(*) as count3 from tablez
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
INSERT INTO MasterTable (count1,count2,count3) 
VALUES ((select count(*) from tablex),(select count(*) from tabley),(select count(*) from tablez))
```

Comment: I had tried the same before posting, but seeing syntax error